# Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- UsersSettingsModalInstanceController

Tags: angularjs

H ieveryone, please help me to do the trick and make my modal work... I'm trying to create a modal to edit users account details. For that in my header I add to the view:

HeaderView.html:

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
      <span>
        {{user.username}}
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
      <li>
        <a ng-click="openUserSettings()">Settings</a>
      </li>    
      <li>
        <a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

And in headerController:

```
controllerScope.openUserSettings = function () {
            $state.go('app.userSettings');
        };
```

In my usersController:

```
app.controller('UsersSettingsController',
               ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'user', 
               function ($scope, $modalInstance, user) {

        $scope.open = function () {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'editAccount.html',
              controller: 'UsersSettingsModalInstanceController'      
            });
        };
    }]);

    // Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
    // It is not the same as the $modal service used above.
    app.controller('UsersSettingsModalInstanceController',
                   ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 
                   function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

        $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
    }]);
```

editAccount.html

```
<div ng-controller="UsersSettingsModalInstanceController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="editAccount.html">  
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Edit Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">             
          <!-- edit form column -->
          <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
            <h3>Personal info</h3>

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="monitorUser2@carris">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Organization:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="carris">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Permission Group:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Monitor">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="monitorUser2@carris">
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <h4>Change Password</h4>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Change Password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                  <span></span>
                  <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally my app.routes file

```
.state('app.userSettings', {
          url: '/allusers/settings/',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/users/editAccount.html',
          resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                  insertBefore: '#load_styles_before',
                  files: ['assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.min.css',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css']
                },
                { serie: true,
                  files: [
                    'assets/libs/chosen_v1.4.0/chosen.jquery.min.js',
                    'assets/libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                    'assets/libs/bootstrap-datatables/bootstrap-datatables.js'
                  ]}]).then(function () {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                      {
                        files: ['app/components/users/usersController.js',
                            'app/shared/layout/utils.js']
                      }
                    ])
                  });
            }]
          },
          data: {
            title: 'Settings',
          }
        })
```

So I add a new option to my header above "logout" option where the user can change is profile information. For that, when he clicks on "Settings" it will popup a new modal where he can change the info. But I'm having troubles injecting the modal instance controller.

When i cLick in "Settings" i get

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- UsersSettingsModalInstanceController
```

Comment: Did u inject it in app?

Comment: Inject $uibModalInstance into controller. Inject ui.bootstrap to required modules

Comment: you mean in my usersController ? I have var app = angular.module('users.controller',[]);

Comment: pp.controller('UsersSettingsController',['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'user', function ($scope, $modalInstance, user) {

Try it this way

Comment: Here's my plunkr with headerController, headerView, usersController and editAccount view.. i also include app.routes file

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal or Angular Modal Service?

Comment: Wher's plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Anxjy3VTknsEDB5CNvWW?p=catalogue

Comment: Not Found in body.

Comment: Dont understand.. you cant found what?

Answer (score 0):

Inject your ModuleInstance to your Angular Module.

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyController", ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'ui-bootstrap', '$etc', '$etc', '$etc', function($scope, $uibModal, $etc, $etc, $etc)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the module of ui bootstrap when your are creating your module:

```
var app = angular.module('wavesys.app.routes', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Extract from the doc (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

> **Installation**
>
> As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.bootstrap module:
>
> `angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`